# Java library for parsing Javadoc comments

Tags: library, java, parser

I would like to be able to programmatically convert [Javadoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc) comments (such as those in the [generated code](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3-generated) of [LWJGL](https://www.lwjgl.org/)) to other formats (such as [Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/)). This would allow me to do things like automatically generating an idiomatic [Clojure](http://clojure.org/) wrapper for LWJGL with human-readable docstrings.

I can pick the Javadoc comments out of a source file using [JavaParser](http://javaparser.org/), but that's where I get stuck. The answers to [these](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7657634/5044950) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15056162/5044950) Stack Overflow questions from 2011 and 2013 recommend using the [Doclet API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/javadoc/doclet/index.html), but according to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34288153/5044950) from 2015:

> The classes in the `com.sun.tools.*` packages should be treated as internal APIs. There are clear warnings in the Java documentation that say that you should not write code that against these APIs.
>
> For example:
>
> - [Why Developers Should Not Write Programs That Call 'sun' Packages](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html)
> - [Closing the closed APIs](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/closing_the_closed_apis)
>
> In Java 8, the header of the class that your code is trying to use says:
>
> > **This is NOT part of any supported API. If you write code that depends on this, you do so at your own risk. This code and its internal interfaces are subject to change or deletion without notice.**
>
> (The bolding is in the original!)
>
> It didn't say that in Java 7 (ouch!) Indeed there are versions of the Javadoc FAQ which seem to *encourage* people reuse the standard doclet classes. Unfortunately, Oracle have decided to close off these classes, and have also made some breaking API changes which reinforces this, whether or not that was the intention of the changes

A Google search for "Javadoc parser" didn't turn up anything but Doclet itself. Since Doclet is unsupported, it seems to me that the best way to solve my problem would be to write a Javadoc parsing library myself. However, it seems implausible to me that such a thing would not already exist. I am not an expert on Javadoc; perhaps there is no standard "Javadoc format" and the question of "how can I parse a Javadoc" [is incorrect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(negative)).

I would like a Java library that

1. takes a Javadoc comment string (such as `"/** foo */"`) and returns some sort of parse tree
2. does not depend on any internal parts of the JDK (such as `tools.jar`)
3. is available through some public Maven repository (such as [Central](https://search.maven.org/) or [Clojars](https://clojars.org/))
4. doesn't say "don't use this" in its documentation

**Does a supported Javadoc parsing library exist, or should I write one myself?**

Comment: The answer you quoted is incorrect. It confuses the `sun.*` packages, about which there is a well-known warning, with the `com.sun.*` packages, about which there isn't. It would be impossible to write a JNDI program without using `com.sun.*`, for example.

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2355296/5044950), `tools.jar`, which includes `com.sun.javadoc.*`, "can't be distributed". So how can I distribute an app that depends on `com.sun.javadoc.*`? Or is that not the package that I would need in order to parse Javadoc comments programmatically?

Comment: You can't. You have to rely on a JDK being installed at the target. But this is  different question. And why would an application without a JDK need to process Java source code?

Comment: Obviously the [JavaParser](https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser) contributors believe that processing Java source code without using the JDK is a perfectly reasonable thing to do. Also, [Clojure doesn't require a JDK](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4807633/5044950), so the use case I gave at the very beginning of my question is another example.

Comment: It isn't the same thing at all. They don't have  a dependency on the JDK because you don't need a JDK to write a parser. You have a dependency on the JDK, no two ways about it. But again this is a new question and nothing to do with this answer.

Comment: It has everything to do with this answer. The Doclet API, in addition to being "NOT part of any supported API" (or perhaps because of that), is also not generally available programmatically at runtime because it requires a JDK. It is _not_ a solution to the problem that I described in my question.

Comment: You could write this yourself with a bunch of effort. Why don't you just use Doclet?  a) It works.. *now*.   b)  if the APIs you want from Doclet ever disappear, you can take the older Doclet source and treat it as yours, as if you wrote it.

Comment: @IraBaxter Could you post a link to the part of the Doclet source license that says that I am allowed to treat it as mine?

Comment: OK, fair point.  My point is that you can choose to do a bunch of work now, or just delay that work.  The worst that  happens is you have to write such a tool when Doclet goes away; that can't be any worse than writing that tool now, with the win being you may never have to.    APIs last a lot longer than anybody will admit.

Comment: @IraBaxter That definitely makes sense, but that would require me to learn the Doclet API, which I wouldn't need to do if I just write the library now. Also, it doesn't address the fact that anything I write that uses the Doclet API becomes more difficult to distribute.

Answer (score 0):

There is a doc2java project which supports this:

[image: doc2java project]

There's also a [search engine](https://www.javadoc.io/) which can host JavaDocs and make them searchable.

**References**

- [doc2java project](https://github.com/BackupTheBerlios/doc2java/tree/master/doc2java)
- [Free Java Doc hosting for open source projects :: Javadoc.IO](https://www.javadoc.io/)

Comment: Isn't this the opposite way? Looks like OP has the Java code and only wants to have the 'javadoc' comments out of it? I think a better tool might be e.g. doxygen and outputting XML output for further processing.

Comment: @albert I just got here from a search engine, and going by the title, I answered the question

Comment: I think more appropriate answers with google can be obtained maybe something like: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/doclet/overview.html or https://tomassetti.me/extracting-javadoc-documentation-source-files-using-javaparser/ or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24727110/javadoc-source-file-parsing

Comment: @albert Thanks. Hopefully the OP will respond.

Comment: Yeah, as @albert said, this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @SamEstep Did you have a look at the suggestions I gave (I didn't look deeply into it so I'm not sure what they are worth in respect to the question) or did you find another solution (if so please add to your question or post as an answer, depending if it is a workaround or a good solution)

Comment: @albert I did; Doclet would not work for reasons I mentioned in the original question, and as that article states, while JavaParser can extract the JavaDoc comments themselves, it cannot parse them (and the relevant issue linked at the end of the article was closed). I have not yet found a good solution.

Comment: @SamEstep Just have a go at doxygen with xml output (just set EXTRACT_ALL to YES and GENERATE_XML to YES) and see what you get in the xml directory, maybe you can parse this further.

Comment: @albert That's a good idea, thanks; I haven't had time to work on this project for a while, but if I come back to it I'll be sure to try that.